# Angular 2+ ngStyle binding with css object having duplicate property

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using ngStyle property binding with my HTML element to bind dynamic style in my Angular component like below:

***example.component.ts***

```
.spinnerStyle = {
            'background': this.color,
            'background': `-moz-linear-gradient(left, ${this.color} 10%, rgba(255,128,0, 0) 42%)`,
            'background': `-webkit-linear-gradient(left, ${this.color} 10%, rgba(255,128,0, 0) 42%)`,
            'background': `-o-linear-gradient(left, ${this.color} 10%, rgba(255,128,0, 0) 42%)`,
            'background': `-ms-linear-gradient(left, ${this.color} 10%, rgba(255,128,0, 0) 42%)`,
            'background': `linear-gradient(to right, ${this.color} 10%, rgba(255,128,0, 0) 42%)`
        }
```

***example.component.html***

```
<div class="loader" [ngStyle]="spinnerStyle">Loading...</div>
```

As we can see my typescript file is having an object representing my CSS style. It is a valid CSS, but an **invalid typescript object** as it is having **duplicate identifiers**. My compilation is failing due to this. What should be the alternate approach?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I did a workaround for my style object by first  creating it as string literal and then converted it to JSON object:

```
this.spinnerStyle = JSON.parse(`{ "background": "${this.color},background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, ${this.color} 10%, rgba(255,128,0, 0) 42%)",
            "background": "-webkit-linear-gradient(left, ${this.color} 10%, rgba(255,128,0, 0) 42%)",
            "background": "-o-linear-gradient(left, ${this.color} 10%, rgba(255,128,0, 0) 42%)",
            "background": "-ms-linear-gradient(left, ${this.color} 10%, rgba(255,128,0, 0) 42%)",
            "background": "linear-gradient(to right, ${this.color} 10%, rgba(255,128,0, 0) 42%)"
        }`);
```

It worked like a charm...

Comment: Ok, I did a workaround for my style object by first  creating it as string literal and then converted it to JSON object, but final json object will only keep the last property!!

Comment: question and answer are posted by you in same time. then why should you post this?

Comment: You can use ngClass. You put your css in your component.css, and use [ngClass]="{'spinnerStyle':condicion}" (when condition it's true, the class is applied)

Comment: @Ajmalsha Aftre posting the question I got it working by doing the workaround within minutes so shared the answer. But still it is not the solution as json object will ultimately keep the last key-value pair. But in CSS all values preserves.

Comment: @Eliseo My styles are very dynamic, and if I will use class it will be according to applied class. I will get these colors as input property.

Comment: @RahulBhooteshwar it is not really a solution if the final json object is only keeping the last value right